# IE javascript problem with break or classname

Tags: javascript, ajax

i'm not really sure whats the problem here, it works with chrome and ff but not ie.

```
var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
newdiv.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
el = newdiv.firstChild.nextSibling;
var next;
do{
next = addpoint.nextSibling;
if(next.className != "commentstyle golduser") break;
}while(addpoint = next);
document.getElementById("testimonialcommentlisting"+id).insertBefore(el,next);
```

error is at this line document.getElementById("testimonialcommentlisting"+id).insertBefore(el,next);

---

```
**UPDATE**
```

ok this is werid, i did some test and i found the problem. the problem is with var el
for chrome and ff el is div element while ie is null.

here comes the weirder problem. By right, newdiv.firstChild should be the div element but i dont know why ff and chrome register it as a text element and clearly my responseText is something like this

```
<div>blahblah</div>
```

i hope somebody understands what i'm talking about.

Comment: Perhaps you should check the "nodeType" of each sibling to make sure you're only messing with HTML element nodes (and not, for example, comments or text nodes).

Answer (score 1):

Your loop follows an odd construction. You're fetching `addpoint.nextSibling` then looking at its `className` attribute, and only ***then*** checking to see if the node is valid. This means on the last iteration through the loop, when `next` is null, you're trying to access the `className` property of `null`.

```
while (next) {
    if (next.className != 'commentstyle golduser') break;
    next = next.nextSibling;
}
```

Without more context from what surrounds this loop I don't know how `addpoint` fits in. It's not necessary just to make the loop work, though if you do need to change `addpoint` there's no reason you can't do so using this loop construction.

The point is that you are never checking `next.className` when `next` is null.

Comment: hi sir, my do loop is doing fine, i checked it many times. and i mistaken error is at this line document.getElementById("testimonialcommentlisting"+id).insertBefore(el,next);

Comment: In that case, what is `id`? It's not defined in the code you shared. Have you checked to see if `document.getElementById()` is returning a valid node for the value you're giving it in IE?